# Sencha GXT XTemplate tpl for inside tpl for

Tags: java, templates, for-loop, extjs, gxt

I'm trying to use XTemplates of GXT 3.0 (similar as EXT) and here are 2 simple java objects that have below relationship:

```
class A {
   String name;
   public String getName() {
       return name;
   }
}

class B {
   String name;

   public String getValue(A a) {
       return a.getName();
   }
}
```

I want to apply XTemplate with 2 arguments (List<< A>> aList, List<< B>> bList) for following template:

```
<tpl for="aList">
    <tpl for="bList">
         ////// Questions? How to call function B.getValue(A) ???
         /////  this does not work for me:  {this.getValue(parent)}
    </tpl>
</tpl>
```

Have any body familiar with such kind request?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a special named object to help you deal with this called `parent` - this accesses the external scope.

```
<tpl for="aList">
    <tpl for="bList">
         Name of inner item, i.e. b.getName() is {name} <br />
         Name of outer item, i.e. a.getName() is {parent.name}
    </tpl>
</tpl>
```

If there was a third loop, you could chain the calls to parent to get out further - `parent.parent.name`.

And if A had a `getPhone()` method, but B didn't, then the `parent` is optional, since clearly you can't be referring to the non-existent `b.getPhone()`.

This same principle is used in [this example](http://www.sencha.com/examples/#ExamplePlace%3atemplates), where the each child has their details printed, along with the parent's. Take a look at the source of the `template.html` file to see how `parent` is used in that case.